# POST-request changed to GET-request after SSL-redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx

i want to Login as a user in my Rails-application. Everything works fine without SSL. When SSL is activated on staging/production there is an SSL-redirect that change my POST-request in a GET-request. So instead of calling the CREATE-method the SHOW-method in my Session-Controller is called. Here are the logs:

```
Started POST "/authentication_customer_user_sessions" for *********** at 2014-07-30 10:42:30 +0200


Processing by Authentication::CustomerUserSessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authentication_customer_user_session"=>{"redirect_path"=>"user_index_path", "login"=>"user", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "account"=>{"signup"=>"with_signup"}, "commit"=>"signin"}
Redirected to https://staging.myserver.de/authentication_customer_user_sessions
Completed 302 Found in 5ms


Started GET "/authentication_customer_user_sessions" for *********** at 2014-07-30 10:42:30 +0200

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for Authentication::CustomerUserSessionsController):
```

In my Authentication::CustomerUserSession-Controller i activate SSL with

```
private  

def ssl_required?
    return false if request.local? || RAILS_ENV == 'test' || RAILS_ENV == 'development'
    true
end
```

So what can i do in my Rails-App to avoid this problem without deactivating SSL for this controller? Thanks for any help!

I'm using authlogic for authentication.

Comment: maybe i have to force SSL in the login-form, so that no redirect will be arranged (?)

Comment: That's how redirect works. Just do request to `https` in first place so no redirect will occur

Comment: thanks @AlexeyTen for your answer. i'm trying to force `https` in my form, but i struggle with the syntax in semantic_form :/ do you know how this works with semantic_form? At the moment it looks like this: `<%= semantic_form_for Authentication::CustomerUserSession.new, :as => :authentication_customer_user_session, :url => authentication_customer_user_sessions_path do |f| %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved my problem. The solution was to force `https` in the login-form. This is my code-snippet:

```
<%= form_for Authentication::CustomerUserSession.new, :as => :authentication_customer_user_session, :url => authentication_customer_user_sessions_url(:protocol => 'https') do |f| %>
```

Or just a bit more generic:

```
<%= form_for Authentication::CustomerUserSession.new, :as => :authentication_customer_user_session, :url => authentication_customer_user_sessions_url(:protocol => (Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?) ? 'https' : 'http') do |f| %>
```